# Sort results by groups of numbers and letters

Tags: loop, sort

I have this code:

```
<?php
$letter=' '; 
query_posts( array (  'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC' ) );
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<ul>
    <?php 
    $title=get_the_title(); 
    $initial=strtoupper(substr($title,0,1));
    if($initial!=$letter)
      {
      echo "</ul><h4>$initial : </h4><ul>";
      $letter=$initial;
      }
    echo '<li>'.$title.'</li>';
    ?>
</ul>
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I show the results by groups, in this way:

```
**&**
'title
"othertitle

**1**
1555555555
1666666666

**2**
2111111111
2555555555

**A**
abbbbbbbbb
annnnnnnnn

**B**
blllllllll
bhhhhhhhhh
```

But I want a group in this way:

```
**0>9**
1555555555
1666666666
2111111111
2555555555

**A**
abbbbbbbbb
annnnnnnnn

**B**
blllllllll
bhhhhhhhhh

**O**
othertitle

**T**
title
```

So I'd like to show:

- results grouped in letters (A>Z) in different group (ex: group A, group B, group C,...)
- results grouped in numbers (0>9) in the same group
- delete the first character from the title with the initial apostrophe (') or quote (").

How can I resolve please?

Comment: You may get a better response via [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)